# Highcharts series format Issue (AngularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

```
$scope.chartSeries= [{"name":"Tokyo","data":["0"," 0.9"," 0.5"," 0.5"," 0.2"," 0.5"," 0.2"," 0.5"," 2.3"," 1.3"," 1.9"," 0.6"]},{"name":"New York","data":["-0.2"," 0.8"," 5.7"," 11.3"," 17.0"," 22.0"," 24.8"," 24.1"," 20.1"," 14.1"," 8.6"," 2.5"]},{"name":"Berlin","data":["-0.9"," 0.6"," 3.5"," 8.4"," 13.5"," 17.0"," 18.6"," 17.9"," 14.3"," 9.0"," 3.9"," 1.0"]},{"name":"London","data":["3.9"," 4.2"," 5.7"," 8.5"," 11.9"," 15.2"," 17.0"," 16.6"," 14.2"," 10.3"," 6.6"," 4.8"]}]
```

When i uses `series: $scope.chartSeries` my charts wont run.

But when i hardcode it i.e.

```
series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
```

My codes runs smoothly. what i am missing? i want to use `series: $scope.chartSeries`

Assiging Data

```
 var chartSeriesArray=[];
   $http.get(url + "?GraphId="+$scope.graph.GraphId)
       .success(function (response) {
                   for (var i = 0; i < response.records.length; i++)
                   {
                       chartSeriesArray.push({
                           "name": response.records[i].name,
                           "data": response.records[i].data.split(",")
                       });
                   }

                   console.log(JSON.stringify(chartSeriesArray));

                //chartSeriesArray=[{"name":"Tokyo","data":["0"," 0.9"," 0.5"," 0.5"," 0.2"," 0.5"," 0.2"," 0.5"," 2.3"," 1.3"," 1.9"," 0.6"]},{"name":"New York","data":["-0.2"," 0.8"," 5.7"," 11.3"," 17.0"," 22.0"," 24.8"," 24.1"," 20.1"," 14.1"," 8.6"," 2.5"]},{"name":"Berlin","data":["-0.9"," 0.6"," 3.5"," 8.4"," 13.5"," 17.0"," 18.6"," 17.9"," 14.3"," 9.0"," 3.9"," 1.0"]},{"name":"London","data":["3.9"," 4.2"," 5.7"," 8.5"," 11.9"," 15.2"," 17.0"," 16.6"," 14.2"," 10.3"," 6.6"," 4.8"]}] 


                   $scope.chartSeries = chartSeriesArray;
          }
```

Comment: Show you controller and view code for binding

Comment: your data has 2 sets of square brackets

Comment: what should i do then?

Comment: @WaqarAhmed - How you assigning data to $scope.chartSeries ? Static data

Comment: see the question! its written there

Comment: @WaqarAhmed - May be try "data": parseFloat(response.records[i].data.split(","))

Comment: No Luck :( still not working

Comment: @WaqarAhmed - Please update the output of chartSeriesArray in your post so we can check what is missing.!

Comment: Updated in #Assiging Data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning data in a wrong format. This should fix the issue:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < response.records.length; i++)
               {
                   var cityData = 
                   {
                       name:response.records[i].name,
                       data:response.records[i].data.map(Number)
                   }
                   chartSeriesArray.push(cityData );
               }
```

**UPDATE** 
maybe the issue is that your data is an array of strings and it should be an array of numbers so you may need to map the string s to numbers: `response.records[i].data.map(Number)`

Comment: @WaqarAhmed - Alex pointed out the problem in your data. You just need to make change when assigning data to scope variable

Comment: See how am i assigning data :S

Comment: Still data is not displaying!

Comment: try changing `data:response.records[i].data` to  `data:JSON.parse(response.records[i].data)`

Comment: Still data is not displaying :(

Comment: You are rite! it was the issue about string & int :P

Answer (score 0):

You first and last entries to data for all four objects are wrong.

```
$scope.chartSeries[0].data[0] = [7.0
$scope.chartSeries[0].data[11] = 9.6]
```

Either remove and make the data valid from the server side (The preferred way.) or make you data valid by some clientside tricks.